Logic Test: The Letter
This morning when I got up I found a peculiar letter in my mailbox. I think it is probably some local person who has gone on a trip and has decided to tell the whole town about it. However, some parts of it seem garbled, and pretty much the only parts of it written with normal words seem uninformative. It goes as follows:

Hi all,
I'm just back from my journey. The scenes were absolutely magnificent. I'll write a description of my trip below. Before that, just some notes: vs lbh haqrefgnaq guvf, gura pbagvahr hfvat jungrire lbh'er hfvat gb haqrefgnaq guvf. N eryl hfshyy gnt rer jbbq orr rkvfgnag, ohg v jbag hfr vg nf vg vf n qrq tvinjnl. ohg n uag vf o'ybj ... npebfgvp
Let's begin: So I started in Denmark, before suddenly finding myself in Romania. Almost immediately after that, I reappeared in India, then Venezuala. After I caught my breath, I had gone to Iceland. The next day, I awoke in Australia, where I spent my entire day. On the third day of my trip, I awoke again in China. Soon, I was in Austria and to end the day, in Romania again.
Some more comments: Here is my email: erq.ureevat@outlook.com. Vs lbh svther bhg jung v jnf npghnyyl qbvat, rznvy zr.
Yours,  Agbuvat Erqureevat.
P.S. I figured out that most apples rot in about 68 or 13 days. They typically don't rot sooner or later, and definitely not 47 days.

I am intrigued  by this letter. Can you guys here help me figure out what it means, and how the man's journey is possible?

$\rightarrow$ Part 2

is the answer "drive a car" + the decrypted first paragraph or is there more?

@LukasRotter Sorry for the late comment, i wasn't able to come in here for a while, but rot47(J6D])

It wasn't a yes or a no question…

Answer:

 rot13ing the encrypted text in the first paragraph gives you understand this, then continue using whatever you're using to understand this. A rely usfull tag ere wood bee existant, but i wont use it as it is a ded givaway. but a hnt is b'low ... acrostic

and

 taking the initials of the countries in the second paragraph gives DRIVIACAR, i.e. "drive a car". The other rot13-encrypted parts spell "red herring" in some variation. Regarding the apples, I think rot68 is "rot13" encrypted with rot5 (numbers only).


This is correct. Good job! However, sentence after his email can be useful, especially if I decide to add a sequel to this. Also, how difficult would you say this is? Thanks.

@GSmith For people active on this website, this puzzle is very easy because it uses common methods in a straightforward way.

Thanks. I just wanted to know that so that I can improve my future posts, since I'm not an active user myself.
